# flextable get clicked column when there is rowspan

Tags: java, gwt, click, flextable

I have a flextable with rowpan. on the click event of the table I am trying to get row index and col index of the table.

if there is no row span at that row there is no problem but 
when there any row span at the row i am getting less col index that should be.
I am getting this:

```
idx : the index i am geting
sCnt: span count at that row
clIdx: column index that i click

idx = clIdx - sCnt;
```

I am using this code:

```
int row = flexTable.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
int col = flexTable.getCellForEvent(event).getCellIndex();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I could not find the solution but I've done somethi,ng I didn't like.
I've written a new widget extending focuspanel and it keeps column and row indexes. These indexes are set in the constructor and I access indexes via my widget's click event.